# How can I run $.ajax through a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I run $.ajax multiple times, it doesn't seem to wait for the ajax call to finish before continuing to run my code. 
As I am using jsonp, setting 'async: false' doesn't work (or so I've read). I have to jsonp to access the Media Wiki api, so changing that isn't an option. I am a beginner at Javascript, is this something I could use a 'promise' for?

```
var articleList = ['Abaft', 'Aspect-oriented%20programming', 'Defecation', 'Feces', 'Perl%20Object-Oriented%20Persistence', 'Poop%20(constellation)', 'Poop%20deck', 'Pooper-scooper', 'Poopy', 'Stern', 'Zoboomafoo'];

function retrieveSummary(jsonp) {
  console.log(jsonp);
}

function fetchSummary() {
  for (var article in articleList) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=' + article + '&prop=text&format=json&section=0&callback=?',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      jsonpCallback: 'retrieveSummary',
    });
  }
}
```

The output I get is the jsonp object of 'Poop (constellation)', which is in the middle of the list. That's the only object I get, despite calling the callback function for each article in articleList.

Comment: "is this something I could use a 'promise' for?". Yes, it is.

Comment: also should let jquery create the callback. Using the same one for each request is a problem

Comment: What do you mean by 'let jquery create the callback', and what is the problem with using the same one for each request?

Comment: change `jsonpCallback:'retrieveSummry` to `success:function(resp){
         console.log(resp);
      }` will see all responses logged to console

Comment: Why doesn't calling 'jsonpCallback' see all responses logged to console?

Comment: You could use `async.parallel()` http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel

Comment: @AllisonStafford jsonp is actually a script request not xmlHttpRequest. Using same function with rapid requests causes tracking/cache issues. See docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

```
var articleList = ['Abaft', 'Aspect-oriented%20programming', 'Defecation', 'Feces', 'Perl%20Object-Oriented%20Persistence', 'Poop%20(constellation)', 'Poop%20deck', 'Pooper-scooper', 'Poopy', 'Stern', 'Zoboomafoo'];

Promise.all(articleList.map(function(article) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=' + article + '&prop=text&format=json&section=0&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json',
    });
  })).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The ajax call returns a promise, Promise.all waits until all promises are resolved then calls back.

Comment: Sure nice to have alternative to `$.when.apply()` and dealing with it's arguments

Answer (score 4):

Have a look on jQuery documentation on how [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function works, I think that may help you :)

Btw, avoid using **async: false** unless you are 100% sure that you need a sync call that can't be archieved with $.when().done/then/always

As @charlietfl pointed, async: false doesn't work with jsonp calls.

From jQuery Documentation:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation

Comment: note that `async: false` wouldn't do anything anyway on jsonp request

Comment: You are damn right! I'll update with your note, thanks for sharing!

Comment: also note `$.when` doesn't accept array so have to use `$.when.apply()` and then loop through `arguments` since results isn't array either. Not hard to do but isn't documented

Answer (score -1):

Try my example.

```
function Timer() {
    this.interval = 1000;
    this.maxloop = 0; //max loop.
    this.onTimerLoop = function () {
    };
    this.onTimerStop = function () {
    };
    var global = this;
    var count = 0;
    var taskID = -1;
    var isWorking = false;
    this.start = function () {
        if (taskID === -1) {
            count = 0;
            isWorking = false;
            taskID = window.setInterval(function () {


                if (!isWorking) {
                    count += 1;
                    isWorking = true;
                    if (global.maxloop > 0 && (count > global.maxloop)) {
                        global.stop();
                    } else {
                        global.onTimerLoop();
                    }
                    isWorking = false;
                }


            }, global.interval);
        }

    };
    this.stop = function () {
        if (taskID !== -1) {
            window.clearInterval(taskID);
            taskID = -1;
            global.onTimerStop();
        }
    };



}

var articleList = ['Abaft', 'Aspect-oriented%20programming', 'Defecation', 'Feces', 'Perl%20Object-Oriented%20Persistence', 'Poop%20(constellation)', 'Poop%20deck', 'Pooper-scooper', 'Poopy', 'Stern', 'Zoboomafoo'];
var timer = new Timer();
timer.interval = 300;
var currentPositionArticle = 0;
var lastCurrentPositionArticle = -1;
timer.onTimerLoop = function () {
    if (currentPositionArticle !== lastCurrentPositionArticle) {
        lastCurrentPositionArticle = currentPositionArticle;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=' + articleList[currentPositionArticle] + '&prop=text&format=json&section=0&callback=?',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            jsonpCallback: "retrieveSummary"
        });

        if (currentPositionArticle === articleList.length - 1) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
};
timer.start();

function retrieveSummary(jsonp) {
    currentPositionArticle++;
    alert(jsonp);
    wait = false;
}
```